# Determine whether $x \equiv y$, $xy \geq 1$, $x = y^2$ are reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric, or transitive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

> Let $x$ and $y$ be integers.
>   Determine whether the following relations are reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric, or transitive.
>
> 1. $x \equiv y \mod{7}$
> 2. $xy \geq 1$
> 3. $x = y^2$

So far in class we have only determined whether sets are reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric, or transitive. How should I approach this when given problems like such?

Comment: These relations was just as well be viewed as the sets of all pairs $(x, y)$ that satisfy them. For example (a) defines the set $\{(x, y) \in \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z : x \equiv y \pmod 7\}$.

Comment: You can easily check the following : if $xRy$, then $(x,y)\in R$

Comment: Please read the entry for [Equivalence Relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation), especially sections 1 - 4 (see top outline).  (In the fourth section, you find information on relations which require anti-symmetry (namely, a partial order).  Once you've read those sections (not more than a page) C'mon back and summarize the definitions in you question post.  We can help you then apply the definitions to the example problem(s).